# bash get files names from string variable

Tags: bash

I have the following content in ${f} variable (this being a string):

```
-rw-r--r--   1 ftp      ftp           407 Jul 20 04:46 abc.zip
-rw-r--r--   1 ftp      ftp           427 Jul 20 05:59 def.zip
-rw-r--r--   1 ftp      ftp           427 Jul 20 06:17 ghi.zip
-rw-r--r--   1 ftp      ftp           427 Jul 20 06:34 jkl.zip
-rw-r--r--   1 ftp      ftp        227820 Jul 20 08:47 mno.zip
```

What I would like to get is only the files names out of it, such as:

```
abc.zip
def.zip
ghi.zip
jkl.zip
mno.zip
```

Comment: Why do you have that string in a variable?

Comment: how are you getting that value in `$f`?

Comment: `${f}` appears to be the output of `ls` and [one should never parse the output of `ls`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)  Tell us what you are really trying to do and we can likely find a solution.

Comment: Yes, the content of ${f} is the output of an ftp ls based command. It might not be a good idea to parse it, but I really have to extract the files names out if. I am sure that the output format for it would not change in the future, based on that I guess I can take my chances with it.

Comment: Now that you mentioned `ftp`, a better way to get the list of files without those unneeded information is `nlst` instead of `ls`, then you won't have to parse the output.

Comment: @MihaiH In ftp, have you tried the `nlist` command?  In my experience, that produces simply the file names in a newline-separated list with none of the extra info that the `dir` or `ls` commands produce.

Comment: @John1024 is right. I had a typo. It's `nlist` not `nlst`.

Comment: I am using ncftpls, and to be clear, I do need the extra meta data related to each file. I don't understand the reason why the question was downvoted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk` to print the last field in each line. Use `<<<` input redirection to use the variable value as input.

```
awk '{print $NF}' <<<"$f"
```

Note that this won't work if any of the filenames have spaces in their names, you'll just get the part after the last space. Unfortunately, parsing `ls` output is not trivial.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Barmar, I really appreciate your help.